# SharedPreferences Returns null value in another class

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Thanks in advance..!

I am developing an android application. In my application i want to store an id in shared preferences

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("MEM1", getTrackID);
                    editor.commit();
```

Based on that id i want to redirect homepage in my application this is also works fine..

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String username = myPrefs.getString("MEM1","");
 if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("")||username.length()==0) {
                        Intent sessionIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dashboard.class);
                        startActivity(sessionIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
```

Now i am entering into Dashboard class, In this class the shared preference value returns as null.
I want to get that id which is in shared preference  to further process of my application. can anyone help me please?

```
   SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        String username = myPrefs.getString("MEM1","");
                        Log.e(TAG, "TRackNoShared: " + username);
```

Comment: Are you sure MEM1 is saving before?

Comment: What is `getTrackID`?

Comment: yes MEM1 saving before

Comment: Have you tried using getDefaultSharedPreferences?:      `prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

Comment: getTrackID means the response after login Success

Comment: getTrackID might be null , please check once

Comment: if getTrackID returns null, How can i go directly to dashboard class?  Here i am entering into Dashboard class after that it returns null

Comment: I think you forgot to check not Empty

Comment: Check this line : username.equalsIgnoreCase("")||username.length()==0.................. It should be not

Comment: Lalit Jadav that is working fine, but my question is after  Intent sessionIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Dashboard.class);
                        startActivity(sessionIntent);
                        finish();

Comment: In Dashboard class i am not getting that value, it returns as null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a class that extends Application for global configuration. In the class I add the below

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

      private static MyApplication sInstance;

     public static MyApplication getInstance() {
          return sInstance;
      }

      public static Context getAppContext() {
          return sInstance.getApplicationContext();
      }

 public static void saveToPreferences(String preferenceName, String preferenceValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
    editor.apply();
         }

   public static String readFromPreferences(String preferenceName, int defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
     }
}
```

And then in your manifest, add `<application  android:name=".MyApplication"`
then from anywhere i just call `MyApplication.saveToPreferences(KEY, VALUE)` and to retrieve i just do `MyApplication.readFromPreference(KEY, Default Value)`.
Good thing is you can overload the methods and have for integer and boolean types etc

Comment: I've added the entire implementation, had omitted the first part

Comment: don't forget to add the class to your manifest as the application name

Comment: what is meant by default value

Comment: you pass a default value so that in the event that it cant retrieve anything maybe because it was not set, it will return the default value to you and you can use it to validate

Comment: String username = myPrefs.getString("MEM1","");  i used like this , I think that why it returns null value, but in my case it contains number 10 i want to retrieve that value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182938/discussion-between-shaik-and-clifford-owino).